# How to Install Composer and Laravel on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: laravel, composer

```
Warning: require(/opt/lampp/htdocs/blog/public/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/blog/public/index.php on line 24

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/opt/lampp/htdocs/blog/public/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/blog/public/index.php on line 24
```

Comment: `composer install`?

Comment: Finish composer install but i can't laravel